# PHP date conversion using strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-formatting

I have a date in the ymd format. Example for 2014-05-28 I actually have: 140528.

I would like to convert it to the date(c") format. Example: 2014-05-28T00:00:00-04:00

I cannot use DateTime::createFromFormat because of my php version. So instead I tried strtotime, but with no success:

```
$d[14]="140528";
$deliveryDate = date('ymd', $d[14]);
$d[14] = date("c", strtotime($deliveryDate));
```

strtotime is not recognizing the original date format as it returns me the 1969 date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it up into parts and then form a valid date out of those parts. Then `strtotime()` will work.

```
$badDate = "140528";
$date = sprintf("20%s-%s-%s",
    substr($badDate, 0, 2),
    substr($badDate, 2, 2),
    substr($badDate, 4, 2)
);

echo date("c", strtotime($date));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/361426)

Comment: Works well, thanks! Don't like the hard coded "20" bit, but I guess it will do for the next 85 years.